# Can a non-cyclic group be isomorphic to a cyclic group and vice-versa?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

I don't think so, because my intuition tells me that if d is an isomorphism from H to G and that a generates H, then d(a) must generate G. However, the Z4 (cyclic) is isomorphic to U(8) (non-cyclic). What is going on here ?

Comment: What is the isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathcal{U}_8$?

Comment: Up to isomorphism, there are two [groups of order $4$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_4)

Comment: Intuition also comes with examples.

Answer (score 1):

No, cyclicity is preserved by isomorphism.

There's only one cyclic group of given finite order;  and one infinite one.  Cyclic groups are *singly generated*. That means that there is at least one element whose order is the order of the group.

And, $U(8)\cong V_4$ is not cyclic,  but is rather the Klein four group. You can check that $\pmod8$, none of $1,3,5,7$ have order $4$.

Indeed,  $1\equiv 1,\,3^2\equiv 1,\,5^2\equiv 1$ and finally $7^2\equiv 1$.